# How can I manually predict the values of a Fixed Effects model?

Tags: econometrics, fixed-effects-model

Suppose I have a fixed effects model where the coefficient for x1 and x2, respectively, are 2 and 4.

Now suppose I have two vectors, X1 and X2, that has test data for variables x1 and x2, respectively.

If I want to predict the values for y, then would it be correct to write:

```
y = 2 * X1 + 4 * X2
```

where y, X1, and X2 are all vectors?

Comment: This assumes the FE for each observation is zero, which might makes some sense depending on how you parameterized the FEs.

Comment: Thank you. This makes sense!

Comment: And it also assumes a linear model.